# Characterizing a norm on sequences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Let $\{a_i\}$ be a sequence of reals such that $|a_i|\geq|a_{i+1}|$ for all $i$, and consider the following norm: $$\|\{a_i\}\| = \sup_k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sum_{i=1}^k |a_i|~.$$  One can see that -- among all decreasing sequences -- this norm is bounded above by the $\ell_2$ norm as explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288966/the-euclidean-norm-and-k-largest-elements), and it is obviously bounded below by the $\ell_\infty$ norm (which just corresponds to the case $k=1$), although neither bound is uniformly tight.  Are there any other norms that this is "similar" to?

Comment: I should clarify that it only applies to *decreasing* sequences.

Comment: Are you allowing the $a_i$ to be negative?

Comment: Google "Lorentz sequence spaces".  Since you are interested only in decreasing sequence, it is more natural to define the norm of a general sequence to be your norm of the decreasing rearrangement of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks @BillJohnson, I'll look into that. Yemon, I edited the question to ask the question more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces you are asking about are called `Marcinkiewicz sequence spaces', see, for example http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~slassall/marcinkiewicz.pdf